# How to make a second input fall in the same line after a first output?

Tags: java

This is my current code:

```
 // Declare variables
    String address;
    String postal;
    String country;
    
    int qty;
    double price;
    
 // Input quantity and price for the iPhones
    System.out.print("Enter the quantities and price of " + phone1 + ": " + "\t");
    qty = sc.nextInt();
    price = sc.nextDouble();
```

Currently when executed, it shows this:

```
Enter the quantities and price of iPhone 10:    1000
1399.99
```

However, I want the price to be right beside the qty like this:

```
Enter the quantities and price of iPhone 10:    1000    1399.99
```

How can I make it that way?

Comment: Don't press Enter after you enter 1000, press spacebar. So you should actually type `1000 1399.99` and press Enter only after you typed 1399.99.

Comment: Is this the only way? Bcus I'd preferably want the desired executed outcome without the need to press spacebar. Unless that's the only way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You should, as @Alex Sveshnikov said, write the numbers with space between them.

If the purpose is just to look prettier, I would suggest to put a new line before entering the first number, such that you have them one under anoher.

`System.out.print("Enter the quantities and price of " + phone1 + ": " + "\n");`

And the output would be:

```
Enter the quantities and price of iPhone 10: 
1000    
1399.99
```